# What is the proper way to do Shiva Pooja?

Tags: shiva, puja

I am doing Shivan pooja the following way:

1. Flowers/prasadam for guru, followed by small shlokam for guru
2. Flowers/prasadam for Ganesh, followed by chanting Om gum ganapathaye namaha 108 times
3. Chanting rudram and doing Shivan abhishekam
4. Abhishekam is done by first pouring water, then milk, then pouring water again.
5. Then decorating Shiva (i.e. flowers, thilakam, etc)
6. Singing Sivan song
7. Finally, showing arthi and singing Mantra pushpam

But is this the proper way of doing so? I am doing this based on readings online, but I want to be advised on proper protocol.

Comment: Wow. You are doing better than most of the people here. Is this daily Pooja or for any specific purpose?

Comment: Every Monday and every Pradoksham (which comes every 2 weeks). So not daily, but not any specific purpose. :)

Comment: @Christian there are procedures for Shiva Puja in Puranas but i feel those methods need not be strictly observed in these days. Shiva needs faith and true devotion.

Comment: [Chapter 11 Shisti Khanda- Rudra Samhita of Shiva Purana](http://www.indianscriptures.com/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/siva-mahapurana/vol-i/chapter-43/topic-1) describes the method of Shiva pooja in detail. But we don't need to follow all the methods mentioned there.  What you are doing is more than enough. If possible, ask as local priest for suggestion.

Comment: Here is a simple shiva puja if u know how to go about things that is.:).Even in temples they follow similar procedure more or less.This puja is like doing a puja to Shiva linga(thats why here Lord is addressed as Samba parameswra).http://www.astrojyoti.com/shiva.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Visit his temple on every Monday with a clean mind and body to pray.
2. Recite [Maha Mrutunjay manthr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahamrityunjaya_Mantra) for as many times as possible. This is
   the spell to overcome fatal diseases and untimely death.
3. Apply a tilak of vibudhi or basm on the forehead during the temple
   visit.
4. Keep chanting lord as “Om Namah Shivaya” continuously in your route
   to temple and back.
5. Perform worship as abhisekam to shiva linga by bhasma, water
6. Always worship lord Ganesha before praying to lord Shiva. He is
   supposed to remove any obstacles in the course of prayer and
   blessings thereon.
7. It will be a good sign to light a deepa or jyoti as it is prayer to
   lord shakti the other form of goddess parvathi the wife of lord
   shiva.
8. If possible offer jilledu flowers (Madar Tree,
   Gigantic-Swallow-Wort, Mudar, Aak) for shiva puja.
9. If possible visit any one of the jyotirlingams near your place if in
   India. Like Varanasi, srisailam, nashik, Ujjain etc.
10. If the prayer is on Monday carry some prasad to temple. If possible distribute to the people there.

**Maha Mrutunjay manthr**

> “Om Tryambakam yajamahe sugandhim pushhtivardhanam
>
> Urvarukamiva bandhanan mrityor mukshiya maamritath.”

**You can keep Shiva Linga at home but you must follow some rules to keep Shiva Linga in your house.**

1. Get up early in the morning take bath.
2. Do a regular prayer to shiva lingam at home during the early morning and also evenings everyday.
3. Wash the shiv linga and apply vibhuti or bhasm.
4. Light a deepa,  Incense sticks, also known as agarbathi can be light besides.
5. Recite “namah shiva” few times.
6. On Mondays especially offer milk or any sweet made with milk to the lord.